# How do I get a text block to display for 5 seconds?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

C# windows phone- How do I get a text block to display for 4 seconds and disappear?

This is what I have:

```
    statusbox.Text = ("Loading...")TimeSpan.FromSeconds(05);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just start a [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) which clears the text afterwards:

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Tick += {
    statusbox.Text = "";
    timer.Stop();
};
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4);
timer.Start();
```

However, if it's meant to indicate while something is loading, why don't you just clear the status text *when you're finished loading*?

Answer (score 0):

This can be better solved using asynchronous functions:

```
// in .NET 4
await TaskEx.Delay(4000);
statusbox.Text = String.Empty;
```

This is just an extra solution to think about since it makes it easier to understand what's going on. You need to use either [Async CTP 3 for Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9983) or [Async targeting pack for VS 2012](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async). In case you are using .NET 5 (e.g. for WP8), you can use Task.Delay instead of the above method.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Scheduling Task](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/scheduling-tasks-windows-phone), it is much better than timer. You can set a Schedule with an Action.

Answer (score 0):

You can also perform an animation for this.